# How to automatically rank items in an array by the sum of certain of their properties?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a little boxing management sim in my spare time. What I'm stuck on is trying to give the pool of boxers their initial rankings.

I have a List<> of Boxers all with random stats. Each individual boxer class then adds all these stats together and has a public variable called 'totalStats'

I want to make the boxer with highest value of totalStats ranked number 1.

How can i do this in a for loop? or is there some other way I should do it?

So for now what I have is this:

```
    void CreateAllBoxers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < startingBoxerCount_HeavyWeights; i++)
    {
        GameObject boxer = new GameObject();
        boxer.AddComponent<Boxer>();
        boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().BuildBoxerStats(
            GetRandomFirstName(),
            GetRandomSurname(),
            GetRandomHomeGym(),
            GetRandomCompany(),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(8, 20),
            Random.Range(Constants.minWeight, Constants.maxWeight),
            Random.Range(Constants.minHeight, Constants.maxHeight),
            Random.Range(18,40),
            Random.Range(Constants.minCommission, Constants.maxCommission));
        boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().SetId(boxers.Count);
        boxer.name = "Boxer_" + boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().GetId(); //this just sets the instance hierarchy name in editor, not the actual boxers name string
        boxers.Add(boxer);
        Debug.Log("Boxer created: name " + boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().GetNameA() + " " + boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().GetNameB() + ", signed to" + boxer.GetComponent<Boxer>().GetCompanySignedTo());


    }
}

void GiveBoxersInitialRank()
{

}
```

Comment: [This question on stackoverflow should help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573047/sort-list-in-c-sharp). By the way, it was the first search engine hit for `stackoverflow sort list c#`

Comment: ok cheers. I couldnt think how to google it. ta

Comment: That 14 parameters looks terrifying.

Comment: lol i know, but better than having to remember to change all those stats manually on their own :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell if you're in C# or not; so **this advice is for c#.**

You can do a simple Linq query to sort arrays:

```
// Order a new list to be sorted by boxers, then transform into an array
ArrayOfBoxers = ArrayOfBoxers.OrderBy(boxer => boxer.totalStats).ToArray();
```

The reason I mention linq is that while there are sorting functions you can use, Linq allows you to use Lamda functions for annoying tasks like this. Ordering dictionaries, lists, arrays, etc.

You could, instead, implement IComparable then make a list from your array, call List.Sort on that and then ToArray that; but the above Linq will do all of that for you in a single line.

Please note that you shouldn't use things like this in code that gets called a lot as this is going to create a list, then create a new array, and finally (in my example) drop your old array; making it likely to cause high memory fragmentation and be slow due to a lot of allocating/deallocating.

Your final option (off the top of my head anyway), which is the most work, is implement a Quicksort (or another sort..) somewhere and do it yourself. This will be efficient on both memory and time if done right, but comes at the cost of having to write custom code for it.

Comment: ok thank you very much. i am using c# (i did tag it c# but didnt think to mention it also). Thank you so much though for giving me example as per above comment link, this is helping me understand and I think it will be a piece of cake from here. Cheers both of you !

Comment: btw, this will only happen at the start of the game when everything is initialising. Tbh tho I am still struggling right now, I don't know what to put where you have put '(boxer => boxer.totalStats), it doesnt recognise 'boxer' in intellisense. Also I dont really need it to be transformed into Array, a list will work fine (i believe). nb. I have used Lamba functions before and have a very vague knowledge of what they do

Comment: i imagine i am supposed to add this code into my above mentioned function rather than inside its own new function. I will keep trying. thanks again